# Mapbox/leaflet layer toggle to default as "off"

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I have a mapbox map with a layer toggler just like the one seen in the link here (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/layers/).

It works great, but I need a solution to default some of the layers to show off or inactive upon initial map load.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A possibly hacky solution would be to add `return link;` to the end of `addLayer`, and when you call `addLayer` for the layer you want toggled off, just add a `.click()` to the end of it to toggle it off immediately.